# If value exists in another column, take value from the original column in the same row, if not nothing

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation

Example data

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  value = c(10, 50, 80, 90, 45),
  value_1 = c(90, 20, 55, 30, 15) 
)

# A tibble: 5 × 2
  value value_1
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1    10      90
2    50      20
3    80      55
4    90      30
5    45      15
```

90 in `value_1` exists in the column `value`. I want to mutate another column `result` that takes `value_1` in that identified row where `value_1` is matched with `value`. If the data does not exist in the column `value`, simply result would equal to `value_1`

Such that the output would look like:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  value value_1 result
  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1    10      90     30
2    50      20     20
3    80      55     55
4    90      30     30
5    45      15     15
```

What I have tried so far is `mutate` with `case_when` but I do not know how to incorporate `which` or whatever to complete the script

```
df %>%  
  mutate(result = case_when(value_1 %in% value ~ 1, 
                            TRUE ~ 0))

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  value value_1 result
  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1    10      90      1
2    50      20      0
3    80      55      0
4    90      30      0
5    45      15      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `match` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  mutate(result = value_1[match(value_1, value)],
         result = coalesce(result, value_1))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   value value_1 result
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1    10      90     30
#> 2    50      20     20
#> 3    80      55     55
#> 4    90      30     30
#> 5    45      15     15
```

or using a `left_join`:

```
df |> 
  left_join(rename(df, result = value_1), by = c("value_1" = "value")) |> 
  mutate(result = coalesce(result, value_1))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   value value_1 result
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1    10      90     30
#> 2    50      20     20
#> 3    80      55     55
#> 4    90      30     30
#> 5    45      15     15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function `fn`

```
fn <- function(x){
    y <- which(df$value_1[x] == df$value)
    if(length(y) > 0) return(df$value_1[y])
    else return(df$value_1[x])
}

df$result <- sapply(1:nrow(df) , fn)

df
```

**output**

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  value value_1 result
  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1    10      90     30
2    50      20     20
3    80      55     55
4    90      30     30
5    45      15     15
```

Answer (score -1):

Where you have 1, use value_1

But, you expected result makes no sense for what you describe.